# How to use UIAutomation in .NET5 or .Net6

Tags: c#, ui-automation, .net-5, asp.net5

I created a webApi solution with 7 projects.

One of them named 'FinanceApp.UIA, below is the SDK I'm using in this project.
Please notice that 'Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App' was included,

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net6.0</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <FrameworkReference Include="Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Folder Include="SimulateType\" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <ProjectReference Include="..\FinanceApp.Comon\FinanceApp.Common.csproj" />
    <ProjectReference Include="..\FinanceApp.IRepository\FinanceApp.IRepository.csproj" />
    <ProjectReference Include="..\FinanceApp.Model\FinanceApp.Model.csproj" />
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

Why 'Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App' is included? Below is what I want to do in this project

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Automation;
using System.Threading;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.IO;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using FinanceApp.Common;

namespace FinanceApp.UIA
{
    public class BaseUia:IBaseUia
    {
        delegate bool EnumThreadDelegate(IntPtr hWnd, IntPtr lParam);

        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        static extern bool EnumThreadWindows(int dwThreadId, EnumThreadDelegate lpfn,
            IntPtr lParam);

        [DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
        public static extern IntPtr GetHwndByClassName(string lpClassName, string lpWindowName);



        /// <summary>
        /// Get handles by process ID
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="processId"></param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        public IEnumerable<IntPtr> GetHwndFromPid(int processId)
        {
            var handles = new List<IntPtr>();

            foreach (ProcessThread thread in Process.GetProcessById(processId).Threads)
            {
                EnumThreadWindows(thread.Id,
                    (hWnd, lParam) =>
                        {
                            handles.Add(hWnd);
                            return true;
                        },
                    IntPtr.Zero);
            }
            return handles;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Get AutomationElement by process id
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="processId"></param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        public IEnumerable<AutomationElement> GetElementsByPid(int processId)
        {
            var handles = GetHwndFromPid(processId);
            return handles.Select(hnd => AutomationElement.FromHandle(hnd));
        }
    }
}
```

Another project named 'FinanceApp.Service', the SDK and reference is as below:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net6.0</TargetFramework>
    <LangVersion>Latest</LangVersion>
  </PropertyGroup>
  
  <ItemGroup>
    <ProjectReference Include="..\FinanceApp.UIA\FinanceApp.UIA.csproj" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

I get an error as below

> The target platform must be set to Windows (usually by including
> '-windows' in the TargetFramework property) when using Windows Forms
> or WPF, or referencing projects or packages that do
> so.   FinanceApp.Service  C:\Program
> Files\dotnet\sdk\6.0.100-preview.1.21103.13\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk\targets\Microsoft.NET.Sdk.DefaultItems.targets 362

Comment: seems i'm not able to attached the screenshot.

Comment: Change target framework like this: `<TargetFramework>net5.0-windows</TargetFramework>` here is a full console app sample: https://pastebin.com/raw/AqBnQUsh

Comment: @WoodYANG you haven't provided any code or even the error message. The part of the error message you posted though seems to explain what you need to do

Comment: Add the code, what i want is to change the target framework from .netcoreapp3.1 to .net5, seems no error in this project, but when I use it in another project (.net5 project) by 'add project reference', the error massage is 'target framework must be set to windows'

Comment: please click the linkage screenshot. it is the solution structure. The code is what I'm doing in one of the project inside the solution. The project is referred by another service project, if I change the TargetFramework to net5.0-windows, it will indicates the project is not compatible in the service project.

Comment: change the target frame to' net5.0-windows' for all projects in the solution as Simon suggested , then it was resolved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change the target frame to' net5.0-windows' for all projects in the solution as Simon suggested , then it was resolved.